# Import iPhoto backup to Photos (Yosemite)

Tags: osx-yosemite, photos, iphoto

I just installed fresh new Yosemite on my MacBook Pro and I realized, there's no iPhoto anymore, but I have moved whole "iPhoto Library" folder to my external hdd.

How can I get all the photos from the back up (iPhoto) to Photos ?

Answer (score 0):

Hold  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  as you launch Photos & it will ask you to choose a library.

Setting it to your external Lib will then prompt it to start conversion. The new Photos Library will be made in the same location as your old iPhoto Library.